# Aura Error Uncaught error in actionCallback : Unable to find 'getExpenses' on 'compound://srinivasareddys.form'

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

Uncaught error in actionCallback : Unable to find 'getExpenses' on 'compound://srinivasareddys.form'.

I'm getting this error. Kindly let me know where i check code.

server-side controller

```
public with sharing class ExpenseController { 
    @AuraEnabled public static List<Expense__c> getExpense(){
        return [SELECT id, Name, Amount__c, Client__c, Date__c, Reimbursed__c, CreatedDate FROM Expense__c]; 
    } 
}
```

client-side controller

```
({ 
   doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
       //Update expense counters 
       helper.getExpenses(component);
   },//Delimiter for future code 
})
```

Comment: public with sharing  class ExpenseController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Expense__c> getExpense(){
        return [SELECT id,Name,Amount__c,Client__c,Date__c,Reimbursed__c,CreatedDate FROM Expense__c];
    }

}

Comment: ({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
       //Update expense counters
       helper.getExpenses(component);
    },//Delimiter for future code
})

Comment: where am change the code kindly let me know asap

Comment: Based on this question, and the answer, and the long back and forth on the answer, I would strongly recommend you spend some time learning lightning components. There is a Trailhead module you can go through that should help with some of these basic questions you are struggling with.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the method `getExpense()` is not located in the client-side helper, but rather in an apex class. If you want to call this method, you can use this general pattern:

```
({ 
   doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.getExpense");
        action.setCallback(this,function(response){
                if (response.getState() === "SUCCESS"){
                    // do something with the expense records
                }
            }
        );
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }, 
    createExpense : function(component, event, helper){
        // do something
    }
})
```

The [Lightning Components Developer's Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_apex.htm) has more information on this topic that you might also find useful.

Comment: i added given code after reload the page im getting below error

Comment: Uncaught error in $A.run() : Unable to find 'createExpense' on 'compound://srinivasareddys.form'.    Kindly let me know @martin .

Comment: @SSR That looks like it is being caused by a different part of the code that wasn't posted here. There might be an attempt to reference named `createExpense()` that is having a similar problem to `getExpense()`

Comment: may i know ur mail id i will drop a mail to you .Please

Comment: @SSR I'm sorry, but I don't give that out. If you are still having trouble, you could edit this question or ask a new one.

Comment: how to call CreateExpense() in apex let me know is it possible for u .@ martin

Comment: @SSR This part of the code wasn't shown in your post. Is it safe to assume that CreateExpense() is an AuraEnabled method in the ExpenseController?

Comment: how to call this method code in apex    <ui:button label="Submit" 
                               labelClass="label" 
                               press="{!c.createExpense}"/>   @martin

Comment: @SSR It looks like what you need here then is a function in the client-side controller named `createExpense` that you can call when this button is pressed.

Comment: how can i call that button is pressed  .Could you let me know .dont mind .im new here .@martin

Comment: @SSR I updated that in my answer. If you look at the controller you will see the function added there.

Comment: I added given code .But, I didn't get any error .But data is not stored .Could you let me know briefly is it possible for you .createExpense : function(component, event, helper){
        // do something       .You has mentioned in code like // do something ha. What I write exact could you let me know briefly ...Advance thanks..@martin

Comment: @SSR That all depends on what exactly you want to do with this function.

Comment: <div class="bootstrap-sf1"> 
        <div class="container">
            <form>
                <fieldset>
                    <ui:inputText aura:id="expname" 
                                  label="Expense Name"
                                  class="form-control" 
                                  value="{!v.newExpense.Name}"
                                  placeholder="My Expense" required="true"/>

Comment: <!-- If you registered a namespace,
                         the attributes include your namespace.
                         For example, value="{!v.newExpense.myNamespace__Amount__c}" -->
                    <ui:inputNumber aura:id="amount" 
                                    label="Amount" 
                                    class="form-control"
                                    value="{!v.newExpense.Amount__c}"
                                    placeholder="20.80" required="true"/>

Comment: <ui:inputText aura:id="client" 
                                  label="Client" 
                                  class="form-control"
                                  value="{!v.newExpense.Client__c}"
                                  placeholder="ABC Co."/>
                    <ui:inputDateTime aura:id="expdate" 
                                      label="Expense Date" 
                                      class="form-control"
                                      value="{!v.newExpense.Date__c}"
                                      displayDatePicker="true"/>

Comment: <ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="reimbursed" 
                                      label="Reimbursed?"
                                      class="checkbox"
                                      value="{!v.newExpense.Reimbursed__c}"/>
                    <ui:button label="Submit" 
                               labelClass="label" 
                               press="{!c.createExpense}"/>
                </fieldset>
            </form>

Comment: this is my component Kindly let me know briefly code.I experted briefly code from you .please @martin

Answer (score 0):

I also get this error too, I figure out I forget to add `controller` attribute for the component.